# jQuery, HTTPS and WooCommerce API: Error 401

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ssl, woocommerce

I am trying to use Basic Auth over HTTPS to invoke the WooCommerce API, from same-origin (localhost), with jQuery. The server is XAMPP on Windows. I am using a self-signed certificate (with CN=localhost). The certificate issues no warnings when I visit the rest of the website. I tried adding the certificate as Trusted Root Certification Authority. I even allowed chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost (even though the certificate is valid). I keep getting "401 Unauthorized".

```
var username = "ck_????????????????????????????????????????";
var password = "cs_????????????????????????????????????????";
var up = username + ":" + password;
var authHeader = "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password);

WooClient.prototype.getProducts = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/myshop/wp-json/wc/v1/products",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
            return true;
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
        return data;
    });
};
```

The same request performed with Advanced Rest Client returns "200 OK" and the desired result in the body.

Comment: Mmmmm, I just noticed that with Edge everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Also noticed that it worked in Edge, but not in Chrome. After I tried stripping the config down to the minimum, it suddenly started working for some reason. After digging some more, it seems like this happens whenever youre *logged in* to the same site.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wp-json/wc/v1/products",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +btoa(username+':'+password)); 
    return true; 
  }
});
```

Of course, exposing your API keys to the browser is a very bad idea, if youre using this for something important :)